# Is there a “repeated annoyance” defense?

Tags: united-states, murder

Let’s say my friend had a little boy repeatedly ride his bike on his lawn. He kept telling the kid to stay off. Then he even had dinner with the boy’s father and brought up the issue.

Now the next day the boy does it again so my friend shoots him execution style in front of his two sisters (who are little girls).

I understand the reaction may have been extreme but keeping in mind the the repeated annoyance, can the sentence be reduced or the charges dismissed? Would the races of the parties matter?

Comment: If this was a real case, name it. That makes clear you would like to have the legal basis explained, and is not political rant.

Comment: I did name the case but the comments were deleted (apparently by moderators). I’m not going to be baited into starting fights with them so it will remain a mystery but if you search the news you might find something.

Comment: @Trish ... but I’m not sure who can edit my questions. If someone with that power searches and finds the case and edits my question to include that information then I will be happy and won’t risk them thinking I am fighting with their decision to remove my comment with the information.

Comment: Why did you name it in comments instead of just editing your question directly to include the name of the case? *If you want it there, **put** it there*.

Comment: @nij Yes but why was it deleted from the comments? That implies that moderators don’t want the information out. So my editing the question will just be seen as fighting with their decision and probably will be edited out again anyway.

Comment: Information relevant to the question, especially reference to a specific case, isn't going to be removed.

Comment: @Oliver You have a severe misunderstanding of the SE model. Comments are not meant for any lasting information and can be deleted at any time. Your comment(s) being deleted is no indicator for anything. Not including relevant information in the question on the other hand is *bad*. If its relevant, it belongs in the question and won't be removed, it doesn't belong in comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There is a defense of [provocation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provocation_(legal))

This doesn’t apply in this instance because the provocation must be such that it would case a *reasonable* person to lose control. No reasonable person shoots a six year old.

Comment: It was a 5 year old, not a 6 year old. But I guess this is the best available answer.